# C# WPF ProgressBar "default" height

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

In WPF, when I put a `ProgressBar` in the `XAML` file, its height is about 2 or 3 pixels by default.

[image: Tiny progress bar.]

**What height should I put for consistency with other Windows applications** (and adjust height depending on dpi resolution, etc.) ? I tried setting `Height="auto"` but the result is the same.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel Name="dockPanel1">
        <ProgressBar Name="progressBar1" Value="33" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <TreeView Name="treeView1" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows Progressbar Guideline has a pretty good starting hint,

[Recommended sizing and spacing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511486.aspx)

Just incase the link goes away:

[image]

Comment: The "funny" thing is that the dimensions are given in DLUs and pixels (I guess the pixels are converted from the DLUs using windows' default parameters?), but not in DVIs (which XAML uses). Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the typical height of other controls is 23.

So, for your progress bar, use the following:

```
<ProgressBar Name="progressBar1" Height="23" Value="33" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
```

You may want to change the height up or down based on the context of where your progress bar will be and how visible you want to make it.  I've seen many apps with a really tall progressbar so that the user is sure to see it.  Just depends on how you want it to look.

Comment: Typical height of other controls is 23 with default fonts and DPI. Just saying... @GeorgesDuperon: In case you have something you want to anchor onto like a label or text block that inherits its text style from the OS, you might want to let it decide the height. It all depends on the requirements really.

Comment: I am pretty sure that WPF values are NOT in pixels, but are a number that would be used as a base, and WPF would take into account the DPI setting and proportionally adjust the height that you set based on DPI settings.

Comment: fair point, I forgot about device independent units since working in web land. I'd still use something else as an anchor though rather than hard-coding the value.

Comment: @Curtis See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/33bdb15c-a04c-4c17-85e1-6c2802f80b90/resolution-independence) for a discussion on the resolution independence of WPF. Basically, it does adjust correctly, although it doesn't do what you might assume.